# text in div displays in safari 8.2, chrome 39, but not in firefox 34. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I have a div tag that is placed within the body of my HTML document like this:

```
    <div id="content_text"></div>​
```

The contents of the div are later set through javascript like this

```
    var content_text = document.getElementById("content_text")
    content_text.innerText = content
```

where content is a string.

additionally, the div is styled like this:

```
        #content_text 
        {
            font-size: 30px;
            font-family: alexandria_n;
            position: absolute;
            top: 280px;
            left: 100px;
            z-index: 1;
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }
```

the font 'alexandria_n' is loaded from a local folder, with @font-face earlier in the style sheet

```
        @font-face
        {
            font-family: alexandria_n;
            src: url("resources/alexandria_n.ttf");
        }
```

**so the issue is, this displays the 'content' string text in Safari and Chrome with all the corect styling, but displays no text in Firefox. There is not a single trace of the div when the page is opened in Firefox.**

I opened the browser console while loading the page in Firefox, and got the following error:

```
downloadable font: kern: Kerning pairs are not sorted., table discarded (font-family: "alexandria_n" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0) source: file:///.../resources/alexandria_n.ttf
```

however, even after changing the div styling to this (replacing alexandria_n with Arial), the div text still doesn't show up in Firefox:

```
        #content_text 
        {
            font-size: 30px;
            font-family: Arial;
            position: absolute;
            top: 280px;
            left: 100px;
            z-index: 1;
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }
```

**I don't understand enough about the nuances of CSS/HTML to have a good way to debug this. Any help would be much appreciated! :)**

Comment: Firefox doesn't support *innerText*, use W3C compliant *textContent* for modern browsers.

Comment: This worked!  however, the 'content' string had newline characters which seem to now be ignored. any suggestions?

Comment: The text is not parsed, it is simply inserted so whitespace is treated exactly like it would be in the markup (i.e. reduced to a single space). See [*W3C DOM Core textContent*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Node3-textContent). If you want to retain line breaks and formatting, create appropriate markup and insert it using [*innerHTML*](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml0).

Comment: Basically its because firefox doesnot use webkit for browser development and support. Hence firefox use w3c complaint textContent attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*innerText* isn't a standardised property, it was introduced by IE and copied by many browsers but not Firefox. The W3C equivalent is *textContent*, but that wasn't supported by IE until version 9 or there about.

You can do something like:

```
function setText(element, text) {

  if (typeof element.textContent == 'string') {
    element.textContent = text;

  } else if (typeof element.innerText == 'string') {
    element.innerText = text;

  } else {
    element.innerHTML = '';
    element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
  }
}
```

then:

```
setText(content_text, content);
```

Comment: Oh, nice answer, I just notice mine doesn't _actually_ let you change the content.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like FireFox has a [different method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent)

You can rewrite a function doing this:

```
function innerPlain(element) {
  return element.innerText || element.textContent;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ocwu8b8s/)